# Why is there no output when I try mapping an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, conditional-operator

So im creating a webpage that utilizes the REST Countries API. I have a useEffect that renders on the first run and store the data into a useState array but when I try mapping it in the body for some reason my ternary operator returns null saying that there is no data in my useState variable. Am I using the ternary operator right? I want to find out why my variable is null when there is clearly data in the variable

code:

```
const LightMode = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res=>{
            let toInsert = res.data.map((country) =>({
                name: country.name.common,
                population: country.population,
                region: country.region,
                capital: country.capital,
                image: country.coatOfArms.png
            }))

            setData((prev) => [...prev, ...toInsert])
        })
    }, [])

    console.log(data)
    return(
        <div>
            <NavigationBar />
            <div className='temp'>
                {data ? data.map((country) =>{
                    <div>
                        country.name
                    </div>
                }) : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LightMode;
```

[image: output]

Comment: You didn't return anything from map

Comment: Besides that, you need to specify the `key` prop with a unique ID on each div rendered in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in your map. You either need to remove the {} or add a return statement. Here I replaced the {} with () to auto return your JSX. You will also want to add {} around the country.name to make that javascript.

```
return(
    <div>
        <NavigationBar />
        <div className='temp'>
            {data ? data.map((country) =>(
                <div>
                    {country.name}
                </div>
            )) : null}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```